# Azure storage error: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

**The Problem:**

I see there are a few questions with this error, but it doesn't solve my issue.

I have a Web API hosted in Azure web application (Dev/Test F1 Tier) that uploads files to Azure storage blob container and saves to Azure storage table, but when I do that, I get the following error:
`"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."`. If anyone can help or has any idea where I can look, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

**I've Tried:**

I have used Application Insights and attached debugger from VS 2019, full stack trace at the bottom.

Connection string (Note '...' to replace full AccountName and AccountKey):
`"StorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=s...001;AccountKey=TJi...nDkw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"`

*On the azure web application side I've done the following:*

I've Allowed all CORS

[image]

I don't use any VNet's

I don't have any Access restrictions

I'm using the connection string taken from `Access keys` under `Settings` on Azure storage

*On the Azure storage side, I've done the following:*

Account kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

I've Allowed all CORS

[image]

I don't use any VNet's

Allow access from is set to All Networks

Code used to upload files

```
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(_AppSettings.StorageConnectionString, 
$"patient-notes-{patientid}");
container.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.Blob);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
blockBlob.Upload(stream);
return blockBlob.Uri;
```

Code to table storage:

```
private readonly AppSettings _AppSettings;
        private readonly CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
        private readonly CloudTableClient _tableClient;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetry;

        public ErrorLogTableStorage(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, TelemetryClient telemetry)
        {
            _telemetry = telemetry;
            _AppSettings = appSettings?.Value;
            _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_AppSettings.AzureTableStorageConnectionString);
            _tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = _tableClient.GetTableReference(AzureStorageTable.ErrorLog.ToString());
            table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }

        public async Task CreateErrorLog(ErrorLogEntity errorLog)
        {
            try
            {
                CloudTable table = _tableClient.GetTableReference(AzureStorageTable.ErrorLog.ToString());
                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(errorLog);
                await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _telemetry.TrackException(ex);
            }

        }
```

Stack Trace for the table storage:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor+<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Infrastructure.AzureTableStorage.ErrorLogTableStorage+<CreateErrorLog>d__5.MoveNext (Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullInfrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: AzureTableStorage\ErrorLogTableStorage.csInfrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 46)
Inner exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException handled at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor+<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectAsync>d__52.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<GetHttpConnectionAsync>d__45.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered>d__71.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor+<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

Comment: Double check that you are really using the correct connection string in your code, this is the most likely cause.

Comment: I'm using the connection string taken from Access keys under Settings on Azure storage, I thought it might be the connection string, but I've tried also with a publish profile from VS, that give the connection string for the storage account but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got this to work, I had to add `AppSettings:` to the application setting.

change from this application setting

[image]

to this

[image]

But why do I need to add `AppSettings:`?

What's the correct way of doing this?